# Half-edge data structure in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, computational-geometry

I implemented half-edge data structure in C++ to generate topological connectivity of 3D objects from a soup of polygons. Its implementation needs features such as pointers, forward declarations etc.

WebGL seems very interesting and I am trying to implement it in JavaScript. I am a Javascript noob. I was wondering if it is feasible to implement half-edge data structure in Javascript, considering there are no pointers or forward declaration available in Javascript.

Comment: do you have any updates?

Comment: I was able to use c++ code for web-application through Wt (http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) so I didn't have to re-implement it in Javascript. However, I believe it is doable in JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be easy to port your half-edge data structure to JavaScript.

JavaScript has no pointers, but has object references which essential the same thing as a pointer (except that you cannot make arithmetic operations on references). Also since JavaScript is dynamically typed, there is no need for forward declaration.

The Mozilla JavaScript Guide may be helpful to you:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide